# Is this a US Army military uniform cape?

Tags: military, uniform, army

[image: Dark cape]I have this heavy wool cape – it looks kinda grey in a few pics,but is black.  It is wool with a red wool lining (the lining is a bit lighter in weight) – there are no arm holes, but two pockets inset into the lining.  It has a black velvet collar and a heavy braid strip below the collar, across the back and coming onto the front shoulders.  When I try it on it comes to just above my 5’2” ankle – so maybe 4 feet in length?  I’ll measure.
The tag says it was made by Christenson.  I googled and there is a Birger Christensen designer (contemporary) and the location of 286-288 Fifth Avenue is now Saks Fifth Avenue.

I’m googling to try to find a source for historic tenants of 286 Fifth Ave.

My mother said this was my father’s West Point cape.  I don’t think so – because it looks nothing like those capes – and because the name/address label that is still partially intact has his address in Alexandria VA, which is in the late 1950’s – early 1960’s.  Perhaps it was made prior to that time? Or?  I don’t know that I have a photo of him wearing it?

Any ideas? [image: Christenson label on crimson lining]

Comment: I have additional photos, just need to resize them to upload.

Comment: Seems in nice shape for a used article of clothing on the order of 3/4 of a century old.

Comment: Was he branched Artillery?  Could be a Mess Dress cape, but I'd have to see more pictures.  See https://www.pinterest.com/pin/antique-clothing--761812093230186503/.  I believe the West Point capes were like the ones at VMI, cadet grey.  Had to buy them outside of regular issue and usually handed down from class to class.  At VMI only first classmen were permitted to wear capes . . .wouldn't know how it was at WP, might take some research.  Hurricane a'comin so other issues are bubbling to the top.

Comment: Yes, he was Artillery, and the pinterest photo is great. Because of the label, I think this was bought outside of regular issue and may have been needed for his service in DC at the Pentagon?  Thanks so much - be safe!

Comment: After WW2, mess dress was not a required article of uniform, however, the well dressed field grade officer either had one or had a friend who had one.  The cape was for cold weather as there was no overcoat for that specific uniform.  One could wear an overcoat with Dress Blues, but not with Mess Dress.  Looks like one to me.

Comment: A copy of [The New York National Guardsman (March 1940)](https://museum.dmna.ny.gov/application/files/3615/7972/0378/NYNG1940_03.pdf) includes an advert on pg. 29 - "Specializing in U.S. army officers' uniforms Christenson Military Tailors 286 Fifth Avenue, New York". Which seems to confirm that it was sourced from a military tailor.

Comment: Thank you, Steve!  Between you and R. Leonard I think I have what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, this cape is, indeed, a US Army cape (note, cape, USN and USMC have similar items of uniform, but are called cloaks).

Officers buy their own uniforms and among the high end items are mess dress (in blue or white) and dress blues. Mess Dress and Evening Mess Dress are the army equivalents to civilian white tie and tails.  Due to the cost of mess dress uniforms, when the occasion calls for mess dress, the dress blue or white uniform may be worn with a bow tie as vice the straight tie.  The army cape may be worn with either mess dress or dress blues as the occasion warrants, usually a formal affair after regular working hours on or off post.

Note this description and following line drawing from pages 125 & 126 of the [2021 uniform regulation, AR 670-1](https://armypubs.army.mil/epubs/DR_pubs/DR_a/ARN30948-PAM_670-1-000-WEB-1.pdf) below.

The cape has been an article of uniform with little changes, with the exception of specified fabrics as time progressed, for 150 years.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You all are the BEST!!  Thank you so much.  I hope you didn't have much damage from Ian.

Comment: @MollyShannon: Don't forget to accept the answer if you feel it is the correct one.

Comment: How do I accept an answer. I highlighted a check mark - is that it?